# How to display taxonomy term reference field as a rendered entity?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy term reference field which are displayed as checkbox.
Each taxonomy term has two fields 
1. description and other
 2. price
I want the description and price field to be displayed alongside the title in field(term refrence).

How can I achieve ut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`taxonomy_term_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view/7) is for displaying a taxonomy term as a rendered entity. If not specified explicitly with an extra parameter, it uses the view mode `full`, which displays all fields, one after the other. But you can adapt that in the admin backend, and also define other view modes. So in your case, the code would be like:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($entity->field_term_reference);
$term_view = taxonomy_term_view($term);
```

This generates a Drupal render array. In case you want to use this in a theme context, add one more line:

```
drupal_render($term_view);
```